# Assets2: Date Field Expectations

Tags: assets

It seems the Date field of an asset is only modified when a file is initially uploaded, thereby representing an upload date or pseudo-created date (date it was created in Assets and not necessarily when the file was created).  Is this correct?

Replacing an existing file with a newly uploaded one does not appear to update the date.  Is that a bug or is that intentional?

Are there any other options for modifying the date other than editing it directly after an asset is replaced or writing a hook to do it automatically?

We're using ExpressionEngine 2.5.3 with Assets 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Date" field is for the user to modify. It does not represent the time the file was uploaded - use "date_modified" for that. On initial upload, the Date is set to the same value as "date modified", so that it has at least some value, but, other than that, it's more of a descriptive field, so, again, use "date_modified".

Comment: That makes perfect sense in relation to templates.  However, a content editor who only uses the control panel and views assets in list view expects the Date field to act like the operating system's file manager, but it looks like that column shows the "date" instead of the "date_modified."  Was that the intention in the context of the control panel?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of perspective. Imagine a blog, where it's owner goes on a trip to, say, India, for five days and takes some pictures. After returning, he/she uploads them all. If the column reflected the date_modified, then the owner would have no way of sorting the images by date in the table view. However, if he/she edited the dates, it all becomes sortable. Sometime in the future we plan on allowing to select the columns displayed, but I'm not sure when exactly that might happen.